# can't download the nested tables properly [edited]

Tags: python, python-requests, screen-scraping

I'm trying to scrap a table from a website. I do the login, go to the page... and, using manually i can see several tables that i need, they are mostly nested but there, the problem is when i run the program, the resultant file donwloads only the headers and the final table(the one with the sums and stuff) i need however to get all the tables.
The problem is, i cannot use Selenium because selenium needs a interface and the server that will download the tables don't have it.

the print of the tables i need to get

[image]

so i need to get all the tables but if i download them normally the files get just the headers and the final  values, does anyone know what to do?
Thanks!

as requested here is the code i am using to scrape the tables:

```
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content)
    tables = soup.findAll("table")
    subtable = next(subtable for table in soup.find_all('table') for subtable in table.find_all('table'))
    for table in tables:
        print '======================'
        print table
        print '==================================='
        for row in table.find_all("tr"):
            for td in row.find_all("td"):
                data = td.get_text()
                print "tds", td

                try:
                    print 'here '
                    print data
                    print '===================='
                    _date = datetime.date((data[6:10]),int(data[3:5]),int(data[0:2]))

                    if data_atual == _data or data_anterior == _data:
                        try:
                            _input = td.find("input")

                            payload = "__RequestVerificationToken=" + _input.get("value")
                            url = "www.Awebsite.com" + row.get('id').replace("row-","")
                            res = session.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)

                            try:
                                file = open("C:\\... filename.json" , "w") 
                                file.write(res.content) 
                                file.close()
                            except Exception as err:
                                exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
                                fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
                                print(exc_type, fname, exc_tb.tb_lineno)
                                print(err)
                        except Exception as err:
                            exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
                            fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
                            print(exc_type, fname, exc_tb.tb_lineno)
                            print(err)
                except Exception as err:
                    pass
```

And here is the HTML area that i need to scrap by. (the problem is, to see the nested tables i need to make an .json request for each  on the table)

```html
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <div id="DataTables_Table_1_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper" role="grid"><div class="row dt-rt"><div class="col-sm-6"><div id="DataTables_Table_1_length" class="dataTables_length"><label><select size="1" name="DataTables_Table_1_length" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_1"><option value="10" selected="selected">10</option><option value="25">25</option><option value="50">50</option><option value="100">100</option></select> Registry</label></div></div><div class="col-sm-6"><div class="dataTables_filter" id="DataTables_Table_1_filter"><label>Filter: <input aria-controls="DataTables_Table_1" type="text"></label></div></div></div><table class="table table-responsive server-table dataTable" data-source="/virtualaccount/entries?userId=<user id>;moffset=0" data-source-property="VirtualAccountEntries" data-source-callback="bindActions" id="DataTables_Table_1">
            <thead>
                <tr role="row"><th data-sortable="true" data-prop="DateCtz" data-render="renderDate" class="sorting_asc" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 121px;" aria-label="
                        Data
                    : activate to sort column ascending">
                        Data
                    </th><th data-prop="Reason" class="sorting_disabled" role="columnheader" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 112px;" aria-label="
                        Type
                    ">
                        Type
                    </th><th data-prop="Description" class="sorting_disabled" role="columnheader" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 218px;" aria-label="
                        Description
                    ">
                        Description
                    </th><th data-prop="FormattedAmount" class="total sorting_disabled" role="columnheader" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 133px;" aria-label="
                        Value
                    ">
                        Value
                    </th></tr>
            </thead>
        <tbody role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all"><tr class="odd"><td class=" sorting_1">31/07/2018 21:00:00</td><td class="">Saldo</td><td class="">Saldo</td><td class="">-106,15</td></tr><tr class="even"><td class=" sorting_1">01/08/2018 21:00:00</td><td class="">Saldo</td><td class="">Saldo</td><td class="">-106,15</td></tr><tr class="odd" id="row-<sale id>"><td class=" sorting_1"><img id="loader-<sale id>" class="row-loader" src="www.Awebsite.com/source.gif" style="display: none;"><a data-id="<sale id>" id="explosion-<sale id>" href="www.Awebsite.com/transactions?entryId=<sale id>" class="explosion" style="display: none;"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" value="<Really long token here>" type="hidden"><i class="show-tooltip fa-explosion-row fa fa-plus-square-o" title="" data-original-title="Visualizar"></i></a>08/08/2018 19:02:23</td><td class="">Transactions</td><td class="">Transaction payment</td><td class="">3,80</td></tr><tr class="subdata"><td>06/08/2018 17:34:43</td><td>Transaction</td><td>Debit transaction with authorization NUMBER.</td><td>$ 3,80</td></tr><tr class="even" id="row-<sale id>"><td class=" sorting_1"><img id="loader-<sale id>" class="row-loader" src="www.Awebsite.com/source.gif" style="display: none;"><a data-id="<sale id>" id="explosion-<sale id>" href="www.Awebsite.com/transactions?entryId=<sale id>" class="explosion" style="display: none;"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" value="<Really long token here>" type="hidden"><i class="show-tooltip fa-explosion-row fa fa-plus-square-o" title="" data-original-title="Visualizar"></i></a>08/08/2018 19:02:23</td><td class="">Transactions</td><td class="">Transaction payment</td><td class="">43,74</td></tr><tr class="subdata"><td>06/08/2018 15:36:01</td><td>Transaction</td><td>Debit transaction with authorization NUMBER.</td><td>$ 43,74</td></tr><tr class="odd" id="row-<Sale ID>"><td class=" sorting_1"><img id="loader-<Sale ID>" class="row-loader" src="www.Awebsite.com/source.gif" style="display: none;"><a data-id="<Sale ID>" id="explosion-<Sale ID>" href="www.Awebsite.com/transactions?entryId=<Sale ID>" class="explosion" style="display: none;"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" value="<Really long token here>" type="hidden"><i class="show-tooltip fa-explosion-row fa fa-plus-square-o" title="" data-original-title="Visualizar"></i></a>08/08/2018 19:02:23</td><td class="">Transactions</td><td class="">Transaction payment</td><td class="">71,07</td></tr><tr class="subdata"><td>06/08/2018 16:12:38</td><td>Transaction</td><td>Credit transaction with authorization NUMBER.</td><td>$ 59,98</td></tr><tr class="subdata"><td>06/08/2018 15:51:33</td><td>Transaction</td><td>Credit transaction with authorization 029530.</td><td>$ 11,09</td></tr><tr class="even" id="row-<another sale ID>"><td class=" sorting_1"><img id="loader-<another sale ID>" class="row-loader" src="www.Awebsite.com/source.gif" style="display: none;"><a data-id="<another sale ID>" id="explosion-<another sale ID>" href="www.Awebsite.com/transactions?entryId=<another sale ID>" class="explosion" style="display: none;"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" value="<Really long token here>" type="hidden"><i class="show-tooltip fa-explosion-row fa fa-plus-square-o" title="" data-original-title="Visualizar"></i></a>08/08/2018 19:02:23</td><td class="">Transactions</td><td class="">Transaction payment</td><td class="">51,52</td></tr><tr class="subdata"><td>06/08/2018 16:02:19</td><td>Transaction</td><td>Credit transaction with authorization NUMBER.</td><td>$ 51,52</td></tr><tr class="odd" id="row-<yet another id for another sale>"><td class=" sorting_1"><img id="loader-<yet another id for another sale>" class="row-loader" src="www.Awebsite.com/source.gif" style="display: none;"><a data-id="<yet another id for another sale>" id="explosion-<yet another id for another sale>" href="www.Awebsite.com/transactions?entryId=<yet another id for another sale>" class="explosion" style="display: none;"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" value="<Really long token here>" type="hidden"><i class="show-tooltip fa-explosion-row fa fa-plus-square-o" title="" data-original-title="Visualizar"></i></a>08/08/2018 19:02:23</td><td class="">Transactions</td><td class="">Transaction payment</td><td class="">75,11</td></tr><tr class="subdata"><td>06/08/2018 09:33:31</td><td>Transaction</td><td>Credit transaction with authorization NUMBER.</td><td>$ 75,11</td></tr><tr class="even" id="row-<Sale ID>"><td class=" sorting_1"><img id="loader-<Sale ID>" class="row-loader" src="www.Awebsite.com/source.gif" style="display: none;"><a data-id="<Sale ID>" id="explosion-<Sale ID>" href="www.Awebsite.com/transactions?entryId=<Sale ID>" class="explosion" style="display: none;"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" value="<Really long token here>" type="hidden"><i class="show-tooltip fa-explosion-row fa fa-plus-square-o" title="" data-original-title="Visualizar"></i></a>08/08/2018 19:02:23</td><td class="">Transactions</td><td class="">Transaction payment</td><td class="">22,21</td></tr><tr class="subdata"><td>06/08/2018 14:31:36</td><td>Transaction</td><td>Debit transaction with authorization NUMBER.</td><td>$ 22,21</td></tr><tr class="odd" id="row-<sale id>"><td class=" sorting_1"><img id="loader-<sale id>" class="row-loader" src="www.Awebsite.com/source.gif" style="display: none;"><a data-id="<sale id>" id="explosion-<sale id>" href="www.Awebsite.com/transactions?entryId=<sale id>" class="explosion" style="display: none;"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" value="<Really long token here>" type="hidden"><i class="show-tooltip fa-explosion-row fa fa-plus-square-o" title="" data-original-title="Visualizar"></i></a>08/08/2018 19:02:23</td><td class="">Transactions</td><td class="">Transaction payment</td><td class="">122,12</td></tr><tr class="subdata"><td>06/08/2018 14:39:01</td><td>Transaction</td><td>Credit transaction with authorization NUMBER.</td><td>$ 122,12</td></tr><tr class="even" id="row-<sale id>"><td class=" sorting_1"><img id="loader-<sale id>" class="row-loader" src="www.Awebsite.com/source.gif" style="display: none;"><a data-id="<sale id>" id="explosion-<sale id>" href="www.Awebsite.com/transactions?entryId=<sale id>" class="explosion" style="display: none;"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" value="<Really long token here>" type="hidden"><i class="show-tooltip fa-explosion-row fa fa-plus-square-o" title="" data-original-title="Visualizar"></i></a>09/08/2018 16:22:56</td><td class="">Transactions</td><td class="">Transaction payment</td><td class="">48,51</td></tr><tr class="subdata"><td>07/08/2018 13:35:55</td><td>Transaction</td><td>Debit transaction with authorization NUMBER.</td><td>$ 48,51</td></tr></tbody></table><div class="row dt-rb"><div class="col-sm-4"></div><div class="col-sm-8"><div class="dataTables_paginate paging_bootstrap"><ul class="pagination"><li class="prev disabled"><a href="#">← Previous</a></li><li class="active"><a href="#">1</a></li><li><a href="#">2</a></li><li><a href="#">3</a></li><li><a href="#">4</a></li><li><a href="#">5</a></li><li class="next"><a href="#">Next → </a></li></ul></div></div></div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and there it is, all the info i can give. thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To help you we'll need to see the code you're using and the HTML you're trying to scrape, preferably as a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Check out that page for help.

Comment: @HarryCutts I've edited the question with the code and the html.

Comment: It looks like there are two parts to this problem: extracting the tokens from the hidden `<input>`s, and making the appropriate requests to the website to retrieve more data. Which are you having trouble with? Have you checked that you're making requests to the correct URLs? (From the `url = …` line, it looks like your code won't form proper URLs at the moment because you're not adding slashes.)

Comment: making the apropriate requests is proving troublesome... even geting the 'post' request with the json data i cant seem to retrive the right data from it... Most of time it returns not the json but the login page html

Comment: OK, so it sounds like this is a problem with making the requests, not the HTML scraping. You might do better to write a new question with a sample of a failing request, and only include your code that makes the request (since the HTML scraping sounds like it's working). Off the top of my head, you might want to compare what headers you're sending with what you see in your browser's inspector when you use the web page.

Comment: @HarryCutts i've created a new question... the main problem is i can't get the right tokens to execute the requests.